# Read process output to both OutputStream and String

Tags: groovy

I have a pretty basic process:

```
Process p = 'foo.exe'.execute()
```

It takes a long time to run, so I want to output to an OutputStream while it is running. Pretty easy:

```
p.consumeProcessOutputStream(System.out)
p.waitForOrKill(TIMEOUT_IN_MILLIS)
```

But now I would also like the output as a String. How can I get that?

Comment: You could capture it in a `StringWriter`, and then print this to `System.out`...  Or use something like the [commons-io TeeOutputStream](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/output/TeeOutputStream.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @tim_yates comments you can use [`StringWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html) to save the process result and get the output as `String` using `toString()` method:

```
def sw = new StringWriter()

Process p = 'foo.exe'.execute()
p.consumeProcessOutputStream(sw)
p.waitForOrKill(TIMEOUT_IN_MILLIS)

def processOutput = sw.toString()
```

If you want to use this `String` to check your process result, maybe an alternative option is to writer the result to a `File`, to do so you can do something similar using [`FileWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html)

```
def fw = new FileWriter("/resultProcess.log")

Process p = 'foo.exe'.execute()
p.consumeProcessOutputStream(fw)
p.waitForOrKill(TIMEOUT_IN_MILLIS)

fw.with {
    flush()
    close()
}
```

Or as also `@tim_yates` suggest to take both at time you can use from `apache commons-io`: [`TeeOutputStream`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/output/TeeOutputStream.html)  and [`WriterOutputStream`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/output/WriterOutputStream.html) to write the result to `String` and to a `File`:

```
@Grab('commons-io:commons-io:2.5')
import org.apache.commons.io.output.TeeOutputStream
import org.apache.commons.io.output.WriterOutputStream

// File outputresult
def wosFw = new WriterOutputStream( new FileWriter("/resultProcess.log") )

// String output result
def sw = new StringWriter()
def wosSw = new WriterOutputStream( sw )

// create teeOutputStream with two outputStreams
def teeOS = new TeeOutputStream(wosFw,wosSw)

Process p = 'foo.exe'.execute()
p.consumeProcessOutputStream(teeOS)
p.waitForOrKill(TIMEOUT_IN_MILLIS)

teeOS.with {
    flush()
    close()
}

def resultProcess = sw.toString()
```